# How to configure options sometime later at runtime?

Tags: c#

I have a .Net 5 Web Api project and want to configure options with some logic. That's why I would like to move the configuration out from the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method and put them into their own service configurator (running during startup). So I came up with this

```
class OptionsConfigurator : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceCollection _serviceCollection;

    public StartupOptionsConfigurator(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        _serviceCollection = serviceCollection;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        /*

            Build the ServiceProvider from the _serviceCollection
            Get the IConfiguration service from the ServiceProvider
            Read the configurationSection from the IConfiguration
            call _serviceCollection.Configure<MyOptions>(configurationSection);

        */

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This won't work because I can't inject `IServiceCollection` to the constructor. Is there a way to configure those options without the need of an instance of `IServiceCollection`?

I can provide another example showing the problem:

Your Api provides a single endpoint to update a specific configuration to change it during runtime (maybe change the database connection string for some reasons).

- Create a new Web Api project
- Create an options class

.

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

- Create a controller

.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> _myOptionsMonitor;
    private readonly IServiceCollection _serviceCollection;
    
    public MyController(IOptionsMonitor<MyOptions> myOptionsMonitor, IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        _myOptionsMonitor = myOptionsMonitor;
        _serviceCollection = serviceCollection;
    }

    [HttpPatch]
    public IActionResult UpdateOptions([FromBody] string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before: " + JsonSerializer.Serialize(_myOptionsMonitor.CurrentValue));

        _serviceCollection.Configure<MyOptions>(x => { x.Text = text; });

        string newConfig = JsonSerializer.Serialize(_myOptionsMonitor.CurrentValue);
        Console.WriteLine("After: " + newConfig);
        
        return Ok(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Call the patch endpoint with a new configuration string in the request body. As expected this doesn't work neither, the injection of `IServiceCollection` is not possible and throws an exception.

Are there any solutions on how to configure options later on?

Comment: Well... You can configure options using IConfigureOptions and inject services into that, but that still happens upon first use. If you're using Singleton options (not Snapshot/Monitor which can be reloaded with latest values) you can just update the IOptions.Value property with a new value (though that will only impact the current app, ie. If replicated it doesn't hit them all). Finally you could write your own Configuration provider that you add into your Config builder that can read settings from any location and be updated how you chose (reading an ext. API or with help from hosted service)

Comment: The answer really depends on what you are *really* trying to do. Are you just trying to make it so that you can update connection strings? Also be advised that simply modifying the values may not be enough. Many service only inject IOptions.. To understand changes they'd need to at the least inject IOptionsMonitor/IOptionsSnapshot and be built to react to updates to the configuration

Answer (score 3):

Reconfiguring options using `IServiceCollection.Configure` is not possible after initialization because `BuildServiceProvider` has already been called. You cannot configure or add any service outside program initialiazation.

To change configuration values you just need to update `appsettings.json` file in `UpdateOptions` action and to use `IOptionsMonitor` everywhere.

When configuring configuration you can specify to reload the configuration file when it changes. In `Program.CreateHostBuilder`:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingConext, configurationBuilder) =>
        {
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingConext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            configurationBuilder.AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true, true);
        });
}
```

In this way `IOptionsMonitor<TOptions>.CurrentValue` will always return the value stored in the configuration file even if it changes.

Comment: IIS used to watch the bin folder for changes. If change detected the site will be restarted. If you plan to change a file make sure it isn't placed inside bin folder and do not plan to change web.config either. These things apply to ASP.NET and IIS surely, but I am not sure in your environment.

Comment: @cly ASP.NET core can watch JSON configuration files without restarting the application. This is a big difference with regarding .NET Framework ASP.NET where a change in web.config triggers app restart.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you should implement your own [ConfigurationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). This would allow you to react to changes in your configuration and then you use IOptionsMonitor (for singleton services) or IOptionsSnapshot (for transient or scoped services) to read the values.

There is a sample implementation for a database based configuration provider over at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-configuration-provider). That would be fairly easy to change to something where you store the values in memory (or wherever you want if you want to persist changes) and then you could expose this to your controller.